# How to modify the position of UIImageViews subviews inside a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm trying to create gaps between the UIImageViews, which are subviews added into a UIScrollView.

And I thought I could do the following by modifying the CGRect of the UIImageView.
CGRect frame = imageView.frame;

```
frame.origin.x = <some values>
frame.origin.y = 0
imageView.frame = frame;
```

By modifying the x values, I assumed it will help me with the position of the UIImageViews inside the UIScrollView.

However, I realized whichever values I set for the frame.origin.x does not really matter. As each UIImageView inside the UIScrollView will be positioned side by side without any empty space.

Comment: I would double check your frame.size.width. Setting the frame.origin.x is the right approach. Perhaps the UIImageViews are still overlapping?

Comment: all my frame.size.width returns me the same value. is the frame.size.width related to the UIImageViews overlapping? Isn't frame.size.width simply the width of the CGRect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing it in the wrong way. You can't edit view's position by

```
view.frame.origin.x = something;
```

You should assign **a new frame**, like this:

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
```

In your case it will look like this:

```
CGRect frame = imageView.frame;
CGFloat frameX = frame.origin.x;
CGFloat frameY = frame.origin.y;
CGFloat frameW = frame.size.width;
CGFloat frameH = frame.size.height;

frameX = <some values>
frameY = 0;

imageView.frame = CGRectMake(frameX, frameY, frameW, frameH);
```

Comment: Hi @Kashiv, I did what you said. Also did a NSLog of the CGRect which reflected the x coordinates I generated for each UIImageView.

Comment: Hi @Kashiv. Thank you. I got it, to make my problem worst, I even had a method that starts rearranging my views even after I added your codes in.